# Move selection sequentially in NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nscollectionview

By default selection in NSCollectionView get moved by arrow keys within one row (or column).

How to make selection *move sequentially*, like items arranged by index?

[Screenshot from developer.apple.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaT1k.png)

Comment: Have you ever find a solution? When I use content array (legacy) mode it behave in that way but if I use flow layout it doesn't.

Comment: No, I haven't find a solution. I tried `float`, `custom`, `grid` and `legacy`, but when selection reached border (left/right) nothing happens. Its stay still when try move selection by keys on keyboard.

Comment: without anything extra it works on legacy mode but not any others. I contacted with Apple Developer Technical Support, they said after checked "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that this would be best handled as a bug report."

Comment: I hope they will fixed this bug. tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked same question to Apple Developer Technical Support, after checked they said "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that this would be best handled as a bug report.". I submitted bug report to Apple's radar. So far no response.

I decided to implement my own solution. Subclass your `NSCollectionView` and override keyDown event.

Swift 4

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if event.modifierFlags.rawValue == 10617090 {
        return
    }
    if event.isARepeat == true && event.keyCode != 123 && event.keyCode != 124 && event.keyCode != 125 && event.keyCode != 126 {
        return
    }
    if event.keyCode == 123 || event.keyCode == 124 || event.keyCode == 125 || event.keyCode == 126 {
        for index in self.selectionIndexes {
            if event.keyCode == 124 && index < YOUR_DATASOURCE_ARRAY.count - 1 {
                self.deselectItems(at: [NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0) as IndexPath])
                self.selectItems(at: [NSIndexPath(forItem: index + 1, inSection: 0) as IndexPath], scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.nearestHorizontalEdge)
                return
            }
            if event.keyCode == 123 && index > 0 {
                self.deselectItems(at: [NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0) as IndexPath])
                self.selectItems(at: [NSIndexPath(forItem: index - 1, inSection: 0) as IndexPath], scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.nearestHorizontalEdge)
                return
            }
        }
    }
    super.keyDown(with: event)
}
```

This interrupts left and right arrow key inputs and move selection to previous/next cell. Since 
"Allows Multiple Selection" has to be NO. Also disable modifier keys as like <kbd>CMD</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>.

If you keep pressing right arrow, when selection arrives to last cell at right hand it jump one row down and keep moving or vice versa for left arrow. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! That's helped me!